# django: 2 templates in 1 view

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views

Sorry for the newbie question

this is what i am trying to accomplish

after filling up the fields in my form and submitting it, the views will send a confirmation code in your email and you will be directed to another template where the it will ask for a code that the views sent.

after submitting, the view will then check if your code matches the random generated code that view sent and if the code is valid then the data will be saved

here is my views

```
def save_page(request):
form = application_form(request.POST)
if request.method == 'POST':

    if form.is_valid():  

        a = (''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for i in range(12)))
        i = 1
        try:
            cde = APPLICANT_DATA.objects.get(code=a)
            i = 0
        except:
            i = 1

        while i ==  0 :

            a = (''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for i in range(12)))
            try:
                cde = APPLICANT_DATA.objects.get(code=a)
                i = 0
            except:
                i = 1

        else:

            emails = form.cleaned_data['EMAIL']
            mail = EmailMessage('Your activation and application code is:  ' + str(a) +", do not show this to anyone", to=[emails])
            mail.send()
            cde = form.save(commit=False)


            return HttpResponseRedirect('verify')

            sub_form = confirmform(request.POST)
            if request.POST['form-type'] == u"verify":

                if sub_form.is_valid():
                    e = sub_form.cleaned_data['code']
                    if form.code == e:
                        form.save()

                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
            else:
                sub_form = confirmform()

            return render(request, 'frontend/verify.html', {'sub_form': sub_form})


else:

    form = application_form()

return render(request, 'frontend/apply.html', {'form': form})
```

i have tried saving the data first then using session I validated the code and edited the data from the database itself but if i think about it, the database will be crowded with data. I just need the verified data

I am really stuck with this and i can seem to find a solution

I'll really appreciate any help, pointers, and tips

Comment: What does this have to do with "2 templates in 1 view"?

Comment: i am currently using 2 templates and 1 view, template A contains the form to be filled up and upon submission(button) you will be redirected to template B and template B contains a single form field that will receive your input (code from email) and upon another submission(button) the code will be verified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Instead of doing what i had originally in mind, what I did is to save the data and then send a link to activate the account/application and if the account is not activated within a set of days the data will be deleted through django commands